# Why am I able to insert a duplicated value into a unique column

Tags: android, android-sqlite

So I want the user to be able to update my table. Besides the default `_ID` column, I also have a `NAME` column, which I declared unique and is the identifier I use for the rows.

Now, for testing purposes, I am inserting the same values into the table. For some reason I find the table has duplicated its rows when using the `insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)` method.

But when I use `insertWithOnConflict(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues initialValues, int conflictAlgorithm)` (where `int conflictAlgorithm` is `SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE`) this doesn't happen.

Basically, this is the translation of how I create my table:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL ON CONFLICT REPLACE, " + 
            COLUMN_NAME_STATS + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_NAME_ABILITIES + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_NAME_PICTURE + " TEXT," +
            " UNIQUE(" + COLUMN_NAME_NAME + ")" + "ON CONFLICT REPLACE" +
            ")";
```

I also tried above without the `UNIQUE()...` clause at the end of the statement, but with a `COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE , " +` declaration.

To simplify, this is what I insert (I only insert names):

```
ContentValues cv;
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
for(String t : someListOfStrings)
   cv.put(MyDBContract.MyDatabase.COLUMN_NAME_NAME,t);  //Where t from {"abc","def","ghi"}
db.insert(MyDBContract.MyDatabase.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
```

I'm populating my output via `"select * from " + MyDBContract.MyDatabase.TABLE_NAME`, which in this case are only 2 columns `ID` and `NAME`

And this is what I get:

```
_id: 1, name: abc
_id: 2, name: def
_id: 3, name: ghi
_id: 4, name: abc
_id: 5, name: def
_id: 6, name: ghi
```

With `insertWithOnConflict` and `SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE` constraint, only what I intended in the first place:

```java
_id: 1, name: abc
_id: 2, name: def
_id: 3, name: ghi
```

Did I create the table wrong or why doesn't this work with the standard insert method? How do I create my table correctly? Or am I forced to work with `insertWithOnConflict`?

Comment: Add WITHOUT ROWID at the end of create table

Comment: In the documentation `insert` says nothing about conflict handling. I'm *guessing* that's why they added insertWithOnConflict in API 8. You may be forced to working with that.